# Как изменить кодировку в mousepad?

Tags: linux, кодировка, xfce

Есть текстовый файл с кодировкой `windows-1251`, но когда я открываю его в `mousepad`, в выпадающем списке такой кодировки нет, кстати, `utf-8` тоже нет.

Вопрос: **как добавить соответствующую кодировку в Xfce?**

[image]

Comment: 1. *кстати, utf-8 тоже нет* — вижу utf-8 даже на вашей картинке. 2. неясно, при чём тут xfce. 3. не видно версии программы.

Comment: У этого файла кодировка не Windows-1251, а очень даже CP866. Кодировка CP866 в списке очень даже есть. Или у вас почему-то нет?

Comment: Хотя кодировки Windows-1251 я в своём Mousepad тоже не вижу. Тем не менее у файла не эта кодировка

Comment: А, я понял идею: в списке отображаются только те кодировки, которыми технически возможно декодировать этот файл. Ваш файл содержит байты, которые нельзя декодировать кодировкой Windows-1251 (потому что у файла кодировка на самом деле CP866), поэтому её и в списке нет. Если вы откроете файл, у которого кодировка и в самом деле будет Windows-1251, то она в списке будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В списке отображаются только те кодировки, которыми технически возможно декодировать этот файл, а он содержит байты, которые нельзя декодировать кодировкой `windows-1251` (потому что кодировка на самом деле `CP866`), поэтому её и нет в списке. Если открыть файл, у которого кодировка в самом деле `windows-1251`, то она будет в списке.